# Determining the truth of some statements about the convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to either provide a proof or a counterexample for the following statements about $\sum a_k$, a series of real numbers.

> (a) $k^2 a_k \to 0$ implies $\sum a_k$ converges.
>
> (b) $\sum (a_k)^2$ convergent implies $\sum (a_k)^3$ convergent.

I know that $ka_k \to 0$ does not imply that $\sum a_k$ converges, because you can just use the example $a_k = \frac{1}{k\log k}$. But if I want to select something of a similar form such that $k^2 a_k \to 0$, there's a problem because the obvious choice, $a_k = \frac{1}{k^2 \log k}$ actually forms a convergent series.

For (b), if $(a_k)^2$ converges, then I don't think that implies anything about the convergence of $(a_k)$, since you could just take $a_k = \frac{1}{k}$ then one diverges and the other converges, but what about $(a_k)^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) You have $k^2a_k\to 0\Rightarrow |a_k|<\frac{1}{k^2}$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

(b) You have $|a_k|^3\leq|a_k|^2$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

In both cases, the comparison theorem gives the conclusion.